# Code fails when attempting to retrieve column headings

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get the column headings returned from SQL stored proc that I have called fine and the data is returning however when I try to access the column headings it fails so it does.

```
Private Sub Refresh_Click()


 Dim Conn As ADODB.Connection, RecordSet As ADODB.RecordSet

    Dim Command As ADODB.Command
    Dim ConnectionString As String, StoredProcName As String
    Dim StartDate As ADODB.Parameter, EndDate As ADODB.Parameter

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set Conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set RecordSet = New ADODB.RecordSet
    Set Command = New ADODB.Command

    ConnectionString = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;DATA SOURCE=DB;INITIAL CATALOG=DB; User Id=****;Password=****;"

    On Error GoTo CloseConnection

    Conn.Open ConnectionString
    SellStartDate = Format(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value2, "yyyy-mm-dd")
    SellEndDate = Format(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Value2, "yyyy-mm-dd")
    StoredProcName = "fsp_PLReportByDates"

    With Command
        .ActiveConnection = Conn
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        .CommandText = StoredProcName
    End With

    Set StartDate = Command.CreateParameter("@DateFrom", adDBDate, adParamInput, , SellStartDate)
    Set EndDate = Command.CreateParameter("@DateTo", adDBDate, adParamInput, , SellEndDate)



    Command.Parameters.Append StartDate
    Command.Parameters.Append EndDate

    Set RecordSet = Command.Execute


    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A7").CopyFromRecordset RecordSet
```

It is here it fails at the point where it trys to get the column headings. All I am getting back is the procedure failed but when i remove the below code that retrieves the column headings it works.

Also may I ask is there a way to automatically add filtering onto the data returned.

```
    For i = 1 To RecordSet.Fields.Count
      Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value = RecordSet.Fields(i).Name
    Next i
```

If I remove the above three lines it works and returns the expected data just not the headings.

```
    RecordSet.Close
    Conn.Close
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub

CloseConnection:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "SQL Stored Procedure Did Not Execute Sucessfully!", vbCritical, "SQL Error"
    Conn.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fields is zero based

```
For i = 0 To RecordSet.Fields.Count-1
  Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i+1, 1).Value = RecordSet.Fields(i).Name
Next i
```

But, put the code before the .copyfromrecordset
rather than after.

Comment: is their a better error i could trap for would give more detail info more used to c# hate vba lol

Comment: Another problem its only creating it vertically I need them to be horzontal across the top of the sheet ?#

Comment: Use `Cells(6, i + 1).Value`

Comment: The problem I think is that the copyfromrecordset in some way "uses up" the recordset, so the fields aren't there. (Probably to do with leaving the record pointer at EOF). In your error handler you should pass through the error object's description and number properties. That would help a bit.

Comment: Thanks guys for helping is there any way to activate the filter automatically without the user having to do it